# Perl first instances of two string matches inside a while loop

Tags: string, perl

I was hoping to ask what the easiest way to find the first instance of a couple of different strings inside a while loop.  I am searching a log on the fly for two strings, the order of the strings is not essential, either can occur at any time.  However, occasionally there are further instances of the same string further down the log (after the first instance), so I am hoping to only collect the first instance of both strings, and     collect the necessary timestamp.  The code I have so far is...

```
while(<$log_DUT>) {
    $fh_DUT->print($_);
    if (m/<\sOPERATOR\s\{[^,]+,\s[^,]+,\s\d+\}\s\[SUB0\]/){
        $dsub1found = 1;
        open (DUTfFILE, ">>", "$TimeDutfsub1");
        print DUTfFILE DUTcurTime(),"\n";
        close (DUTfFILE);
    }

    if (m/<\sOPERATOR\s\{[^,]+,\s[^,]+,\s\d+\}\s\[SUB1\]/){
        $dsub2found = 1;
        open (DUTfFILE, ">>", "$TimeDutfsub2");
        print DUTfFILE DUTcurTime(),"\n";
        close (DUTfFILE);
    }
    last if ($dsub1found & $dsub2found == 1);
}
```

The script works ok, and successfully captures timestamps when it matches the correct string (regex) triggers, however it continues to capture further instances of the same string should the loop still need to wait for the second regex string (and vice versa).

I had a go at starting the if statement with (for example) if $dsub1found != 1, but with no luck, the string is never found and my script timesout.

The other worry I had was as to whether it was wise to do a couple of string searches in the same while loop.

Thanks for reading this,
 MikG

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
while (<$log_DUT>) {
    $fh_DUT->print($_);
    if (!$dsub1found && m/<\sOPERATOR\s\{[^,]+,\s[^,]+,\s\d+\}\s\[SUB0\]/){
       ...
    }

    if (!$dsub2found && m/<\sOPERATOR\s\{[^,]+,\s[^,]+,\s\d+\}\s\[SUB1\]/){
       ...
    }

    last if $dsub1found && $dsub2found;
}
```

But why all the repetition?

```
my @TimeDutfsub = ( $TimeDutfsub1, $TimeDutfsub2 );

my @dsubfound;
while (keys(%seen) != 2 && ($_ = <$log_DUT>)) {
    $fh_DUT->print($_);
    if (my ($n) = m/<\sOPERATOR\s\{[^,]+,\s[^,]+,\s\d+\}\s\[SUB([01])\]/){
        if (!$dsubfound[$n]++) {
           open(my $DUTfFILE, ">>", $TimeDutfsub[$n]) or die $!;
           print $DUTfFILE DUTcurTime(),"\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Ikegami, this looks to be the sort of thing I was after.  The repetition is purely due to me being a beginner with Perl, but eventually with practice I'll hopefully be able to shorten my scripts in future to make them more efficient.  But as it is, it is clearer for my understanding for me to work with the repetitive format for now.  I tried your shortened script, but it fell over at '$TimeDutfsub$n' saying that '$TimeDutfsub' needed defining

Comment: Re "The repetition is purely due to me being a beginner with Perl", sorry, I meant that to be rhetorical. I could have said "But it would be easy to eliminate all that repetition.

Comment: Re `$TimeDutfsub`, I didn't notice the leading `$`. I thought you creating files named `TimeDutfsub1` and `TimeDutfsub2`. You would have to use an array. `my @TimeDutfsub = (..., ...);` and use `$TimeDutfsub[$n]` (Updated answer to use the array.)

Answer (score 2):

Well, first of all you seem to need to match those two strings in one interation of the while loop (based on the fact, that there are two separate if statements). For that case, you should initialize $dsub1found and $dsub2found to zero at the beginning of every iteration.

Second, '&' is a bitwise and operation, it is probably not what you want. I assume you meant '&&'.

```
if ($dsub1found && $dsub2found == 1)
```

this checks, if $dsub1found is true and $dsub2found equals 1. If the initial values of those two variables were 0, then

```
if ($dsub1found && $dsub2found)
```

would be enough. However if you want both of them to be equal to 1, then you need:

```
if ( $dsub1found == 1 and $dsub2found == 1 )
```

If it still won't work, try printing out the $dsubfound variable values at the end of the while loop for debugging purposes. Maybe print out the input too, and see what is happening.

Answer (score 2):

First off all I would say you are lucky unless you planned it

Your if statement should be working because

( 1 & 1  ) = 1 only  which you are correctly checking against 1

and even the precedence of == over & also works for you

( $a & $b == 1 ) => ( $a & ( $b == 1 ) )

Case 1 a=0 , b=0  => ( 0 & ( 0 == 1 ) ) => ( 0 & 0 ) => ( 0 )False

Case 2 a=0 , b=1 =>  ( 0 & ( 1 == 1) ) => ( 0 & 1 ) => ( 0 ) False

Case 3 a=1 , b=0 =>  ( 1 &  ( 0 == 1) ) => ( 1 & 0 ) => ( 0) False

Case 4 a=1 , b=1 => ( 1 & ( 1 == 1) ) => ( 1& 1) => ( 1) true

You test seems to be working for me , My file input was  " a sd b a 1 b a 2 b " offcourse in new line and it only print a b for the first instance

```
while ( <$FH> )
{
  if ( $_ =~ /a/ )
  {
    $flag_a=1;
    print $_ ;
  }
  if ( $_ =~ /b/ )
  {
    $flag_b=1;
    print $_ ;
  }

  last  if( $flag_a & $flag_b ==1 );

}
```

Check if you are somewhere playing with your dsub1found and dsub2found value because your if condition is very much dependent on that. I suggest yu use above advice and make your id condition robust .